# AG-Grid Custom Drop down issues with selectize

Tags: jquery, angular, ag-grid, ag-grid-angular, selectize.js

I am working on ag-grid with Angular and I need to make my custom dropdown component appear in the popup on double click as it appears in cell editor and also to make it appear properly like other cells. we can create a dropdown in two ways.

First with `cellEditor` and second with custom component. I would like to use `cellEditor` with [selectize](https://www.npmjs.com/package/selectize) jquery but it doesn't seem to work. Hence I am using [selectize](https://www.npmjs.com/package/selectize) with a custom component

```js
{
  headerName: "Status",
  field: "status",
  suppressMovable: false,
  type: "drop down2",
  colId: 5,
  cellClass: "actions-button-cell",
  cellEditor: 'dropdown', //Either this 
  cellEditorFramework: CustomDropdownComponent // or this
},
```

with the custom component, I had to use this CSS to make the dropdown visible which makes it appear outward, and also it is appearing above the row selection.

```css
::ng-deep .actions-button-cell {
  overflow: visible;
}

::ng-deep .ag-row {
  z-index: 0;
}

::ng-deep .ag-row.ag-row-focus {
  z-index: 1;
}

::ng-deep .ag-root,
::ng-deep .ag-body-viewport,
::ng-deep .ag-body-viewport-wrapper {
  overflow: visible;
}
```

[image]

Now, this looks bad and if I don't use the css above, the drop-down will be hidden within the row.

Secondly, let say I use `cellEditor`, I can't seem to integrate it with [selectize](https://www.npmjs.com/package/selectize) jquery. Below is the dropdown code for `cellEditor`

```js
function getDropDown() {
  function DropDown() {}
  
  DropDown.prototype.init = function(params) {
    alert('here');
    this.select = document.createElement('select');
    // this.select.value = params.value;
    this.select.classList.add('email-select');
    this.select.style.height = '100%';
    this.select.style.width = '100%';
    $(this.select).selectize({
      valueField: 'name',
      labelField: 'name',
      placeholder: 'Select',    
      options: [
        {
            description: 'Nice Guy',
            name: 'Brian Reavis',
            imageUrl: 'http://www.fashionspictures.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/11/short-hairstyles-for-a-square-face-42-150x150.jpg'
        }, 
        {
            description: 'Other nice guy',
            name: 'Nikola Tesla',
            imageUrl: 'http://www.fashionspictures.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/11/short-hairstyles-for-a-square-face-42-150x150.jpg'
        }
      ]
    });
    // let option = document.createElement('option');
    // option.value = "One";
    // this.select.append= option;
  };
  
  DropDown.prototype.getGui = function() {
    return this.select;
  };
  DropDown.prototype.afterGuiAttached = function() {
    this.select.focus();
  };
  DropDown.prototype.getValue = function() {
    return this.select.value;
  };
  DropDown.prototype.destroy = function() {};
  DropDown.prototype.isPopup = function() {
    return false;
  };
  
  return DropDown;
}
```

This gives an error selective function does not exist and sometimes it works but doesn't fully apply selective on the select field. Kindly help me out with any of the two ways.

Expected Result:

I have identified two options. If I could find a solution for cellEditor, It would be great else just find a solution for the dropdown appearing a bit outward and above row selection. Thanks!

Comment: could u reproduce ur issue on plunk or stackblitz so that others can help u easily? also, are you working with Angular or Vanilla JavaScript?

Comment: Please read the question clearly i have written everything in it including that I am using Angular. I just want to know how to use selective jquery with angular in ag gird. or just tell me how to solve the cell appearing above the cells on hover. I don't think any reproducible code is required and I have provided all main code which is responsible for custom dropdowns ,

Comment: @Mr Khan, Did this problem solved. Please update the answer.

Comment: Yes i did. Will provide the answer by today.

Comment: This is the plunker link-  https://plnkr.co/edit/z3V7TIUR5MItNspK . I was trying to add jQuery UI menu same as selectize.js dropdown. The solution is same for both.